# Windows Powershell 'if' always returning $true - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: powershell

Question pretty much says it all.  I have a simple script (below) but the IF won't cooperate.  It always evaluates to true even when the values don't match.  Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$pos = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position
$x = $pos.X
$y = $pos.Y

while ($true)
{
  
  Write-Host "on loop strt: x = $($x), y = $($y)"

  $check = (($x -eq $pos.X) -and ($y -eq $pos.Y))
  write-host $check

  if (($x -eq $pos.X) -and ($y -eq $pos.Y))
  {
      for ($i = 0; $i -lt 2500; $i++)
      {
        $pos = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position
        $x = ($pos.X % 1024) + 1
        $y = ($pos.Y % 768) + 1
        [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($x, $y)
        for ($d = 0; $d -lt 1000; $d++) {} #add a little delay
      }
  }

  Write-Host "On loop exit: x = $($x), y = $($y)"

  Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

  $pos = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position
  $x = $pos.X
  $y = $pos.Y
}
```

Comment: You initialize $x = $pos.x and $y = $pos.y before entering the loop and then again before reaching the end of the loop so each time through the loop the If statement is going to be true.  You need to change your logic so that some point the If test will be False.

Comment: At the bottom of the while loop you are always reassigning `$x and $y to `$Pos.x` & `$Pos.y` respectively so when you get back to the If statement both sides of the `-and` evaluate to true.  What's the intent?

Comment: Can you actually explain what you're trying to do?

Answer (score -1):

Issue seemed to be trying to compare directly against pos.X and pos.Y -- I added 2 more variables $a and $b to compare against.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$pos = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position
$x = $pos.X
$y = $pos.Y

$a = $x
$b = $y
while ($true)
{
  if ($x -eq $a -and $y -eq $b)
  {
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt 2500; $i++)
    {
        $pos = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position
        $x = [int]($pos.X % 1024) + 1
        $y = [int]($pos.Y % 768) + 1
        [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($x, $y)
        for ($d = 0; $d -lt 1000; $d++) {}
    }
  }
  else 
  { 
    $pos = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position
    $x = $pos.X
    $y = $pos.Y
    $a = $x
    $b = $y
  }

  Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

  $pos = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position
  $x = [int]$pos.X
  $y = [int]$pos.Y
}
```

Comment: He's reassigning $x and $y at the end of the loop which is the cause of them being equal to the $pos coordinates since the if statement is executed literally milliseconds after that assignment. Adding more variables to the mix doesn't solve that.